# Why isn't my regex matching uppercase characters and underscores?

Tags: java, regex, string, syntax

I have the following Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String var = "ROOT_CONTEXT_MATCHER";
    boolean matches = var.matches("/[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/");
    System.out.println("The value of 'matches' is: " + matches);
}
```

This prints: `The value of 'matches' is: false`

**Why doesn't my `var` match the regex?** If I am reading my regex correctly, it matches any String:

- Beginning with an upper-case char, A-Z; then
- Consisting of zero or more:

  - Lower-case chars a-z; or
  - Upper-case chars A-Z; or
  - Digits 0-9; or
  - An underscore

The String "`ROOT_CONTEXT_MATCHER`":

- Starts with an A-Z char; and
- Consists of 19 subsequent characters that are all uppper-case A-Z or are an underscore

What's going on here?!?

Comment: Your string doesn't start with or end with `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the forward slash characters at the beginning and at the end of the regex. They don't have any special meaning here and are treated as literals. Simply remove them to get it fixed:

```
boolean matches = var.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
```

If you intended to use metacharacters for boundary matching, the correct characters are `^` for the beginning of the line, and `$` for the end of the line:

```
boolean matches = var.matches("^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");
```

although these are not needed here because `String#matches` would match the entire string.

Comment: matches has `^` and `$` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **regex delimiers** i.e. `/` from Java regex:

```
boolean matches = var.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
```

That can be further **shortened** to:

```
boolean matches = var.matches("[A-Z]\\w*");
```

Since `\\w` is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (word character)